# FHIR isSummary in type profile

Tags: hl7-fhir

What does isSummary=true mean in a type profile?  Especially, what does it mean in the "root" element of a type:

```
<element>
   <path value="CodeableConcept"/>
   <short value="Concept - reference to a terminology or just  text"/>
   <min value="0"/>
   <max value="*"/>
   <type>
      <code value="Element"/>
   </type>
   <isSummary value="true"/>
</element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's meaningless.  There should be a constraint that isSummary can only be declared on child elements of resource profiles.  It makes no sense anywhere else.  Can you submit a change request?

Comment: don't agree. I agree it's meaningless on the root, but it's not meaningless on the elements inside a base type definition. And it's repeated on profiles of either resource or type, even though it can't be changed

Comment: So you expect some data type properties to be included in summaries and others to be stripped out?  I agree that once set, isSummary could propagate into profiles, but I'm not sure of the purpose of propagating information that can't be overridden or changed.

Comment: well, not sure what the policy is, but yes, there needs to be something. And we have other information that can't be overridden or changed but that is propogated into profiles